# CSS float different sized div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a little problem with a div 2 that wont go bellow div 1 (see images bellow). I am going to be continueing this on (more div going along) and because of that I don't want to split off the to smaller divs. any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: This is what it looks like now]

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

```css
.large,
.small,
.long-down {
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
}
.small {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
.large {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="large"></div>
  <div class="large"></div>
  <div class="large"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="large"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the wrapper's width to 200px since they're all floating big piece would then be forced the bottom -- yeah?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/azhbeshc/

Comment: Well I have an answer but it splits sections the two smalls into a container of their own.

Comment: Will this grid always look the same or is it going to be dynamical?

Comment: @UncleIroh Hi and thanks for the help. I can not but a fixed width because I am going to be adding more squares e.g. small, small, large large, small, small, and this goes on but in a random.

Comment: @j08691 Hi and thanks for the help. I can not but a fixed width because I am going to be adding more squares e.g. small, small, large large, small, small, and this goes on but in a random.

Comment: @Alex hi and thanks for the help. It is going to be dynamic and I am going to be adding more squares e.g. small, small, large large, small, small, and this goes on but in a random way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a solution that works for any number and order of boxes of different sizes, [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (a javascript solution) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that look like it could work but I am looking for a more css only rout first.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve this using just css unless you wanted the grid to be always the same or follow some pattern. But even then it would be tedious if the number of boxes is large enough.

Comment: I did have a feeling that might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.large,
.small,
.long-down {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.small {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 1px
}
.large {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 301px;
}
.pull-left {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="large"></div>
  <div class="large"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. I can not split it into different areas because I am going to be adding more squares e.g. small, small, large large, small, small, and this goes on but in a random.

Answer (score 0):

i think http://masonry.desandro.com/ can help you in this.
It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space

Comment: Thanks, that look like it could work but I am looking for a more css only rout first.